How to improve polars lazy scan and pivot operation?
I have a pipeline where I am using pl.scan_ipc to lazily scan a collection of feather files, each corresponding to a dataframe with a unique 'market' value. I want to calculate a value for each loaded dataframe, and have it as a column in the output with it's market value as the column name.
# sample_paths = ['market1.fth', 'market2.fth', 'market3.fth']
query = (
    pl.scan_ipc(sample_paths, memory_map=False)
    .filter(some_condition)
    .select(pl.col('time'), pl.col('market'), pl.col('value').do_something())
    .collect()
    .pivot(on='market', index='time', values='value')
)
┌─────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────┐
│ time                ┆ m1        ┆ m2        ┆ m3   │
│ ---                 ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---  │
│ datetime[ms]        ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64  │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════╡
│ 2023-03-10 08:00:00 ┆ 0.023035  ┆ 0.000126  ┆ null │
│ 2023-03-10 08:01:00 ┆ 0.023     ┆ 0.000126  ┆ null │
│ 2023-03-10 08:02:00 ┆ 0.023     ┆ 0.000126  ┆ null │
│ 2023-03-10 08:03:00 ┆ 0.023034  ┆ 0.0001255 ┆ null │
│ 2023-03-10 08:04:00 ┆ 0.0232051 ┆ 0.000125  ┆ null │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴──────┘

This operation works fine for a small number of inputs, and I can successfully collect the series for all inputs (~500 dataframes of ~1_000_000 rows), but the pivot operation at the end is extremely compute expensive and slow and I'm not sure if I can do it lazily?

Each row requires you to scan through all the files (cause you have data from every market in one row), so to do it lazily you need to somehow read all the 500 files in parallel

@RomanPekar Yes, sorry, the issue isn't in loading the data lazily, as the data can fit in memory in one long series, the issue is in the pivot operation at the end, which eats memory and crashes.

if pivot() operation itself is something which causes out of memory, you can probably try using DataFrame.partition_by() to split DataFrame into chunks, and then .concat() pivoted chunks together.
Something like this:
chunks = df.partition_by("time")
# in your case you would probably want to partition by bigger time range

pl.concat(
    ch.pivot(index='time', columns='market', values='value') for ch in chunks
)

┌─────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────┐
│ time                ┆ m1        ┆ m2        ┆ m3   │
│ ---                 ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---  │
│ datetime[ms]        ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64  │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════╡
│ 2023-03-10 08:00:00 ┆ 0.023035  ┆ 0.000126  ┆ null │
│ 2023-03-10 08:01:00 ┆ 0.023     ┆ 0.000126  ┆ null │
│ 2023-03-10 08:02:00 ┆ 0.023     ┆ 0.000126  ┆ null │
│ 2023-03-10 08:03:00 ┆ 0.023034  ┆ 0.0001255 ┆ null │
│ 2023-03-10 08:04:00 ┆ 0.0232051 ┆ 0.000125  ┆ null │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴──────┘

out of interest, you could also check duckdb pivot statement to see if it is more memory-efficient:
duckdb.sql("""
    pivot df
    on market
    using any_value(value)
    group by "time"
    order by "time"
""").pl())

┌─────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────┐
│ time                ┆ m1        ┆ m2        ┆ m3   │
│ ---                 ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---  │
│ datetime[ms]        ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64  │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════╡
│ 2023-03-10 08:00:00 ┆ 0.023035  ┆ 0.000126  ┆ null │
│ 2023-03-10 08:01:00 ┆ 0.023     ┆ 0.000126  ┆ null │
│ 2023-03-10 08:02:00 ┆ 0.023     ┆ 0.000126  ┆ null │
│ 2023-03-10 08:03:00 ┆ 0.023034  ┆ 0.0001255 ┆ null │
│ 2023-03-10 08:04:00 ┆ 0.0232051 ┆ 0.000125  ┆ null │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴──────┘


The existing answer looks great - here is an additional thing you can try.
Another option may be "lazy pivot" as described in the 4th code block example in the pivot docs.
I've adapted an example from the docs more towards your data.
Note that if you don't know the resulting column names ahead of time, you would have to do a collect to determine these. But to do this, you can just continue to collect in the same place and then give the lazy pivot style a go. Not sure about performance / memory pressure relative to calling pivot, but worth a shot.
If you do know the resulting column names ahead of time, you can hardcode the values and should be able to avoid the need to collect altogether. This would be the lazy pivot. Again not entirely sure on performance/memory, but worth a go.
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": [
            datetime(2023, 3, 10, 8, 0),
            datetime(2023, 3, 10, 8, 1),
            datetime(2023, 3, 10, 8, 2),
            datetime(2023, 3, 10, 8, 0),

        ],
        "market": ["m1", "m1", "m1", "m2"],
        "value": [6, 7, 3, 2],
    },
    schema_overrides={"time": pl.Datetime("ms")}
)

# Start with a normal pivot, to prove the "lazy pivot" produces the same results
df.pivot(index="time", columns="market", values="value")
# shape: (3, 3)
# ┌─────────────────────┬─────┬──────┐
# │ time                ┆ m1  ┆ m2   │
# │ ---                 ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
# │ datetime[ms]        ┆ i64 ┆ i64  │
# ╞═════════════════════╪═════╪══════╡
# │ 2023-03-10 08:00:00 ┆ 6   ┆ 2    │
# │ 2023-03-10 08:01:00 ┆ 7   ┆ null │
# │ 2023-03-10 08:02:00 ┆ 3   ┆ null │
# └─────────────────────┴─────┴──────┘

# Now the "lazy pivot"
# `maintain_order=True` only set to achieve reproducible result for demonstration
# You shouldn't really need to use it

# Hardcode these if you know them ahead of time, this will give you the "lazy pivot"
markets = ["m1", "m2"]
# Aren't sure of your unique column values before you run the code?
# Instead of hardcoding them, do this to gather them at run-time
markets = (
    df
    .get_column("market")
    .unique(maintain_order=True)
    .to_list()
)

(
    df
    .group_by("time", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        # `agg` aggregates into list when no aggregation is specified
        # Use first as we know there will only be a single element
        pl.col("value").filter(pl.col("market") == market).first().alias(market)
        for market in markets
    )
)
# shape: (3, 3)
# ┌─────────────────────┬─────┬──────┐
# │ time                ┆ m1  ┆ m2   │
# │ ---                 ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
# │ datetime[ms]        ┆ i64 ┆ i64  │
# ╞═════════════════════╪═════╪══════╡
# │ 2023-03-10 08:00:00 ┆ 6   ┆ 2    │
# │ 2023-03-10 08:01:00 ┆ 7   ┆ null │
# │ 2023-03-10 08:02:00 ┆ 3   ┆ null │
# └─────────────────────┴─────┴──────┘


